# MySQL WHERE variable

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause

i have this sting for example: `11,22,33`

and this is me `table`:

```
ID   /   content
---------------------
1    /  11,15,18,20,22,28,29,30,
2    /  10,11,17,20,22,27,33,40,
3    /  4,8,9,15,22,23,24,31,33,
4    /  10,11,20,22,30,33,40,41,
5    /  5,6,7,10,11,22,28,30,33,
6    /  10,11,12,13,14,15,20,22,
```

---

id **1** contains only 11 and 22

id **2** contains all items from strin: 11 and 22 and 33

id **3** contains only 22 and 33

id **4** contains all items from strin: 11 and 22 and 33

id **5** contains all items from strin: 11 and 22 and 33

id **6** contains only 11 and 22

---

How to create me MYSQL command to read only items with ID: 2,4,5

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE content ???
```

Comment: This would be *a lot* easier if the database was normalized.  You're running into the exact same problem everybody has when they try to store multiple values in a single column.

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: SELECT t.* FROM table t WHERE t.content LIKE '%11,%' AND  t.content LIKE '%22,%' AND  t.content LIKE '%33,%'... It's not a good db structure

Comment: @Javaluca That would not work. You also find entries with 222,333,111,

Comment: SELECT t.* FROM table t WHERE (t.content LIKE '11,%' OR t.content LIKE '%,11,%' ) AND (t.content LIKE '22,%' OR t.content LIKE '%,22,%' ) AND (t.content LIKE '33,%' OR t.content LIKE '%,33,%' ).. better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `find_in_set`

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE find_in_set ('11',content) and find_in_set ('22',content) and find_in_set ('33',content)
```

For more information read the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)